# Start my Activity when another app (start with Intent) stop

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm running another app through the Internet. When it is closed I want to see my app. I think I need to use FLAG_TASK, but I don't know what exactly

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "I'm running an app through the Internet"? Could you explain how you think you have to use `FLAG_TASK`, or preferably provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you have tried.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.........", "com.Activity"));
                startActivity(intent);`

Comment: to be honest, I did not try, because I could not understand the documentation. I need to somehow correctly apply FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, and maybe some other